# specifying the log path for IE driver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to specify the IE Driver log path for this I used the Command-Line.Code as follows

```
var optionsIe32 = new InternetExplorerOptions
                {
                    IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
                    EnsureCleanSession = true,
                    BrowserCommandLineArguments = "--log-file=\"C:\\IE.log\"
                };

var _webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(pathContainingIE32DriverServer, optionsIe32);
```

But the log file is not getting updated when an error occurs.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mostly there. It is specified in the `InternetExplorerService` class:

```
var service = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.LogFile = "C:\IE.log";
service.LoggingLevel = InternetExplorerDriverLogLevel.Trace;
```

Modify the `LoggingLevel` to what you actually want, you should see the possibilities are `Debug`, `Error`, `Warn`, `Info`, `Fatal` and `Trace`. I believe `Trace` level logging is the most comprehensive.

Remove the `BrowserCommandLineArguments` from the `optionsIe32`, and then pass the `InternetExplorerService` into the `Driver` construction like normal, along with your already made options:

```
var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(service, optionsIe32);
```

Comment: This seems out of date. In my v2.24.0.0, there is no property called `LogFile` nor one called `LoggingLevel`. Am I missing an extension definition somewhere?